# Backbone.js Routers confusion (pushState: true, trailing slash)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am using Backbone's router with `pushState:true` to handle my site's urls. Examples of URLs include:

- http://domain.com/John
- http://domain.com/John/
- http://domain.com/John/photos
- http://domain.com/John/my-latest-photos-2012

**Problem**: When the user goes to http://domain.com/John/, the expected function `photos` is executed. However when the user goes to http://domain.com/John without the trailing slash, nothing happens; my guess is that the trailing backslash defined in `root` prevented this.

**Router**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'photos',
        'photos': 'photos'
    },

    viewing_username: $('#viewing_username').val(),  // eg: 'John'

    photos: function() {
        console.log('photos');
    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: '/' + app.viewing_username + '/'
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(e) {
    app.navigate(e.target.getAttribute('href'), true);
});
```

---

### 2nd Attempt

**Problem::** This time I removed the trailing backslash in `root` and http://domain.com/John now triggers the route. The problem this time comes when the user is at http://domain.com/John (which I believe is treated by the browser as a page named `John`), so when the link (with attribute `data-toggle="tab"`) is clicked, the url is changed to http://domain.com/Johnphotos without the seperating `/`.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your 2nd attempt should work if you update backbone to the latest version. See this discussion:

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/pull/1505

The changes above were merged 8 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

While @shioyama's answer is correct, I often bypass this strangeness by using wildcard routes, where possible.

For example:

```
routes:
  'dashboard(/*subroute)': 'index'
```

Of course, this is not a possibility for many apps, however, it's saved time for me in the past.